# Cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p((T))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I feel very confused about why adding n-th roots of unity to $\mathbb{F}_p((T))$ would give $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}((T))$. (Is this true?)

Comment: It is not even true for the field $\mathbf F_p$ (forget Laurent series) or for $\mathbf Q$, or any field at all if $n > 1$: the polynomial $x^n-1$ is not irreducible if $n>1$, so adjoining an $n$th root of unity to a field will give an extension of degree at most $n-1$, or more precisely at most $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: @KCd Can I ask if there's a relation between $\mathbb{F}_p((T))$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}((T))$? Is the latter a splitting field of some polynomial of the former?

Comment: Of course the latter is a splitting field of *some* polynomial over the former: it is a finite extension (of degree $n$) and all finite extensions are splitting fields of some polynomial. Your question really has nothing to do with Laurent series fields. Can you view $\mathbf F_{p^n}$ as a splitting field of some concrete polynomial over $\mathbf F_p$?

Comment: If I may add $\varepsilon$ to @KCd’s response, when you go from $\mathbb F_p((T))$ to $\mathbb F_q((T))$, what’s going on is almost totally visible all the way down in the extension $\mathbb F_p \subset\mathbb F_q$. It’s just a constant-field extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true. Simplest counterexample? It’s $p=2$, $n=3$, where the cube roots of unity are quadratic over the base, just as they are over $\mathbb Q$. So the extension field is $\mathbb F_4((T))$,

Comment: If I may go further and climb on a soapbox, I would urge everyone to do hand computation with finite fields, especially those beyond $\mathbb F_p$.